# Following a trend to fill the missing values in R

Tags: r, function, trend

I have a reference dataset :

```
lookup = structure(list(v = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26), TI = c(0.913066666666667, 
0.70784, 0.584704, 0.502613333333333, 0.443977142857143, 0.4, 
0.365795555555556, 0.338432, 0.316043636363636, 0.297386666666667, 
0.2816, 0.268068571428571, 0.256341333333333, 0.24608, 0.237025882352941, 
0.228977777777778, 0.221776842105263, 0.215296, 0.209432380952381, 
0.204101818181818, 0.199234782608696, 0.194773333333333, 0.1906688, 
0.18688)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Dividing each element of the column `TI` by the previous one I will have :

```
library(dplyr)
trend = lookup$TI/lag(lookup$TI)
```

with this trend as a reference I would like to fill the NA values in my test file :

```
test = structure(list(events = c(5, 179, 256, 192, 117, 35, 35, 11, 
15, 3, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0), v = c(3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 26), TI = c(NA, 0.0795651909763371, 0.0587914615737312, 
0.0640542134644949, 0.0621684208232864, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame")
```

In test file, I would like to replace the `test$TI = NA` with considering the trend. this means :

```
test$TI[6] = test$TI[5]*trend[6]
test$TI[7] = test$TI[6]*trend[7]
...
```

for `test$TI[1]` I should create the `trend` function as :

```
library(dplyr)
    trend = lag(lookup$TI)/lookup$TI
```

then :

```
test$TI[1] = test$TI[2]*trend[2]
```

My question is how could I do it automatically? Since I have a lot of those `test` file which `NA`'s positions are not always the same.

Comment: you could calc trend\*value for every case first: trend_imp = test$TI*trend. Then you could replace all test$Ti which are NA by their trend value: test$TI[which(is.na(test$TI))] = trend_imp[which(is.na(test$TI))]

Comment: @TinglTanglBob !!! Thank you but this is not solving the issue ! Have you tested the script you have written?!!

Comment: i havent, but i guess the problem is that i've forgotten to include the lag for trend_imp